# Visual Studio MSTest doesn't stop on breakpoint when [ClassInitialize] tag present

Tags: debugging, mstest, breakpoints

On my first MSTest project (VS2015) I encountered the following problem, if I have

```
    [ClassInitialize]
    public void Exe20_Run()
    {
    }
```

The debugger doesn't stops on breakpoints.
The debugger will stop on breakpoints if I change it to

```
    [TestInitialize]
    public void Exe20_Run()
    {
    }
```

So, I guess that for some reason, the  **[ClassInitialize]** damages the debugger functionality...
I need the  **[ClassInitialize]** but also debugging capability is wanted.

Could you please help?

Thanks,
Liat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For [ClassInitialise] you don't have the correct signature. Try the following:

```
    [ClassInitialize]
    public static void Exe20_Run(TestContext t)
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("YO!");
    }
```

Add your breakpoint, go to Test menu -> "debug all tests" (or CTRL-R, CTRL-A) and it should stop.